# Click HTML element without Id or Name with JavaScript in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, href

I'm new programming with JavaScript, I'm making and app to Loggin automatically in the Web of my University and get some data.

In JavaScript for change a value or make and action I first need to find the element in the HTTP code with:

document.getElementsByName   or
document.getElementById

But if I have this piece of HTML code with no Id or name:

```
<a href="/wal/gupmenug.menu?p_sistema_c=ALUMNOS&amp;p_sistemaid_n=3&amp;p_menupredid_n=3&amp;p_pidm_n=617047&amp;p_majr_c=617047" target="Menu">ALUMNOS</a>
```

How can I get the href, or click them, or click the item that contains it?

Comment: If there is single anchor tag then you can find it via tag element. If more than one then you can find it via root->child->anchor tag element.

Comment: Can u get me an example, there is only one in this page, but the link send me to another page when are a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the element with `document.querySelector("a[target='Menu']")`. Works since Android 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for the anchor tag in the body of page. This is done using below code:

```
$('body').find('a')
```

But the only issue is, there can be multiple anchor tags on the page. In order to pick your anchor tag of interest, you can compare the target attribute which has a value "Menu" in your case. Below is the code for that:

```
$('a[target="Menu"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <body>

         <a  onclick="myFunction()" href="/wal/gupmenug.menu?p_sistema_c=ALUMNOS&amp;p_sistemaid_n=3&amp;p_menupredid_n=3&amp;p_pidm_n=617047&amp;p_majr_c=617047" target="Menu">ALUMNOS</a>


        <script>
     function myFunction() {

      var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
     alert(list[0].href);
  return false;

   }
  </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```